# Validating javascript decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using the following regexp to validate numbers in my javascript file:

```
var valid = (val.match(/^\d+$/));
```

It works fine for whole numbers like 100, 200, etc, however for things like 1.44, 4.11, etc, it returns false. How can I change it so numbers with a decimal are also accepted?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var valid = (val.match(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/));
```

Matches:

```
 1  : yes
 1.2: yes
-1.2: no
+1.2: no
  .2: no
 1. : no
```

---

```
var valid = (val.match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/));
```

Matches:

```
 1  : yes
 1.2: yes
-1.2: yes
+1.2: no
  .2: no
 1. : no
```

---

```
 var valid = (val.match(/^[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/));
```

Matches:

```
 1  : yes
 1.2: yes
-1.2: yes
+1.2: yes
  .2: no
 1. : no
```

---

```
var valid = (val.match(/^[-+]?(?:\d*\.?\d+$/));
```

Matches:

```
 1  : yes
 1.2: yes
-1.2: yes
+1.2: yes
  .2: yes
 1. : no
```

---

```
var valid = (val.match(/^[-+]?(?:\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)$/));
```

Matches:

```
 1  : yes
 1.2: yes
-1.2: yes
+1.2: yes
  .2: yes
 1. : yes
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
^[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: "4." is technically a valid decimal number but this regex won't match that. You should make the `\d+` digits in the group optional.

Answer (score 3):

isNaN seems like a better solution to me.

```
> isNaN('1')
false
> isNaN('1a')
true
> isNaN('1.')
false
> isNaN('1.00')
false
> isNaN('1.03')
false
> isNaN('1.03a')
true
> isNaN('1.03.0')
true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept decimals (including <1) and integers, with optional + or - signs, you could use valid=Number(val).

Or a regexp:

```
valid=/^[+\-]?(\.\d+|\d+(\.\d+)?)$/.test(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

!isNaN(text) && parseFloat(text) == text