# how to resolve the bug in the decimal validation code?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

it will for 21.22 or 1.11 or something..
but the error is it will allow dot in front of digit and it allow multiple dot for example 123.2.2

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <script type="text/Javascript">
function testNum(inval)
{
 var ex = /^\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/;
 if(ex.test(inval.value)==false){
   inval.value = inval.value.substring(0,inval.value.length - 1);
  }
}
</script>  </HEAD>   <BODY>
 <input type="text" id="" onkeyup="testNum(this);" />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating javascript decimal numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495402/validating-javascript-decimal-numbers)

Comment: What's wrong with a dot in front? You coded the regex like that btw :-) Also, I can't see how this would match `123.2.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to allow multiple dots for me, but the `\d*` means that the starting digit(s) is (are) optional.

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

Comment: it will allow dot after entering digit for example 123.11 is inital value after that when i moved cursor in the first position of digit for example .123.11 it allows that is the problem

Comment: @MarirajSankar okay, but the expression I provided to you does not allow that

Answer (score 2):

Change `\d*` to `\d+` (`+` is the equivalent of `{1,}`) to be sure to have at least one digit before your dot.

As for the multiple dot problem, no it doesn't match several dots.

Also, you may want to change your `\d{0,2}` to `\d{1,2}`, it doesn't really have any sense to match 12. for example.